# Access query using calculation

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to make a query using a calculation with Date().
I have a field named [Currentordue] and a field named [duedate]. What I'm trying to accomplish is making a query to limit the results by "if [currentordue] equals "due" or if [duedate] minus today's date is less than 30 days."

I've tried a few different ways but always seem to end with either an error or with no results showing (which would be an error as well since I know there are fields that are due).

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to use two different date conditions:

```
SELECT Table1.Currentordue, Table1.duedate, DateDiff("d",[duedate],Date()) AS Expr1
FROM Table1
WHERE (((DateDiff("d",[duedate],Date()))<30)) OR (((Table1.Currentordue)=[duedate]));
```

Comment: I figured that's what it was, tried it out and it worked exactly like I needed it too! Thanks for the help!!